# Create instance of object every nth time through a loop

Tags: c#

Apologies if I'm struggling to word this properly. OOP is not my expertise but I'm very much trying to learn.

How do I create an instance of an object on say, every third iteration of a loop?

Within a loop, I need to assign values to an object, but the property to assign a value to will depend on the result of a case statement. Once each property of the object has been assigned, I then need to add that object to a list of objects of the same type.

If I create the object before the loop is entered, then my list just contains the same result over and over again, because (I've read) that the list only contains a reference to the object, and if the object is then changed, so does the list.

If I create the object within the loop, then obviously, I'll get a new object each time with just one of the properties assigned to it by the time it adds it to the list. The list would contain different results, but only the last property would be assigned, as a new object is created each time.

What I assumed you could therefore do was create a new object whenever all of the properties had a value assigned to it (or at the start, when none had). So, since my object has three properties, each time through the loop, I would like to add a new object whenever an int iCounter was 0, add the values, and increment iCounter, then when iCounter is 3, set to 0. However, when I attempt to create an object inside of an if statement, the rest of the program doesn't see the object exists.

I also assumed, I could maybe attempt some kind of macro substitution, which is what I would normally resort to in Fox, however, (I've read) that this is a big no-no in c#.

Any ideas?

```
try
{
    cProducts Product = new cProducts();
    SqlConn2.Open();
    rdr2 = SqlComm2.ExecuteReader();
    int iScanLine = 0;
    while (rdr2.Read())
    {
        iScanLine++;
        Product.product = rdr2["product"].ToString();
        Product.sOrder = rdr2["order_id"].ToString();
        switch (rdr2["detail"].ToString())
        {
            case "Quantity":
                Product.quantity = Convert.ToInt16(rdr2["display_value"]) ;
                break;
            case "Option":
                Product.Option = rdr2["display_value"].ToString();
                break;
            case "Size":
                Product.Size = rdr2["display_value"].ToString();
                break;
        }
        if (iScanLine == 3)
        {
            lProducts.Add(Product);
            thisPage.sProducts.Add(lProducts[lProducts.Count() - 1]);
            iScanLine = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The `%` (modulus) operator gives the remainder of integer division. Thus, if `n % 3 == 0` then n is divisible by 3.

Comment: Note that this actually has very little to do with object-oriented programming per se.  What you're really asking is "how do I do something every X iterations of a loop"?  The fact that the "do something" in this case is "instantiate a new object" is entirely ancillary.

Comment: Maybe you want to re-consider the SQL query returning the data to fix your problem in the first place? Looks like you could modify the query to return one single row per item.

Comment: Agreed with the SQL query - I had thought about that.

Comment: As for the modulus operator, I might be understanding you wrong, but my problem isn't that I don't know how to do something every nth time (though I like your solution to that) - it's more of a case of how do I create the object every third time - it won't seem to let me do that because the rest of my code will complain that the object doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, and that suggests that the strategy of relying on the object to exist in every loop iteration is itself problematic.

The real issue is that this is a kludgey (and fragile) design. Consider structuring the code so you create one object per iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You could just change this bit:

```
if (iScanLine == 3)
{
    lProducts.Add(Product);
    thisPage.sProducts.Add(Product); //<-- We know the object just added is still in Product
    iScanLine = 0;
    Product = new cProducts(); //<-- Create a new object to start populating
}
```

Also, I know that .NET framework is quite new, being only a decade old, but you might consider reading the  [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx):

> **X DO NOT** use Hungarian notation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have table with four columns, where each product represented in three consecutive rows

```
product | order_id | detail   | display_value
A         X          Quantity   5
A         X          Option     Foo
A         X          Size       XL
B         X          Quantity   2
...
```

And you are trying to read products. I suggest you to store current product name and compare it with last product name. If name is changed, then you are reading data of next product, thus you can create new product and add it to list of products:

```
IDataReader reader = SqlComm2.ExecuteReader();
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
Product product = null;

while (reader.Read())
{
    var name = reader["product"].ToString();

    if (product == null || product.Name != name) // check if new product
    {                        
        product = new Product(); // create new product                     
        product.Name = name; // fill name
        product.OrderId = reader["order_id"].ToString(); // and order
        products.Add(product); // add to products
    }

    object value = reader["display_value"]; // get value from row

    switch (reader["detail"].ToString())
    {
        case "Quantity":
            product.Quantity = Convert.ToInt16(value);
            break;
        case "Option":
            product.Option = value.ToString();
            break;
        case "Size":
            product.Size = value.ToString();
            break;
    }      
}
```

As you can see, I also refactored naming - *PascalCase* for properties, *camelCase* for local variables, no Hungarian notation. Also new names for properties introduced - `Product.Name` instead of odd `Product.Product`, `OrderId` instead of `sOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Modulus operator to check whether the iterating variable is divisible by expected `n`th value or not

```
if(value % 3 == 0)
{
  //do stuff
}
value++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly adding the same `Product` to your list, and never create a new one.  When you get to the end of your loop, it'll appear as though you've only got a single item in there.

After you've added your item (within the `if (iScanLine == 3)`), I suspect you want to create a new item: `Product = new cProducts()`.

Also, I would like to reference this particular comment that you make in your question:

> If I create the object before the loop is entered, then my list just
>   contains the same result over and over again, because (I've read) that
>   the list only contains a reference to the object, and if the object is
>   then changed, so does the list.

The following code will result in 5 *separate* objects being added to a list:

```
List<cProducts> list = new List<cProducts>();
cProducts Product = new cProducts();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    list.Add(Product);
    Product = new cProducts();
}
```

You are correct that the list only contains references to the objects - but you are not changing any of the objects; you are creating new ones.  This is a fundamental programming principle, and I'd suggest you take the time to understand how it works before moving on.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that makes a lot of sense. Super impressed at the speed of response here!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand completely but the following loop whould use a counter to execute every third time

```
int isThirdTime = 0; //Test condition for third time equality
while (true) //neverending loop
{
   if (isThirdTime == 3)//test for 3rd time
   {
      // add to list
      isThirdTime = 0; //reset counter
   }
   isThirdTime++; // Increase the counter
}
```